# Filter records within dbcontext object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6 database first approach.

I have three tables:

1.SystemRoles

2.MasterAppMenu

3.EmployeeRoleMenuMappings

A SystemRole can have multiple MasterAppMenu, so this is one to many relationship.

This i am trying to do.

```
private myEntities entities = new myEntities();
var roleMenuMappings = entities.SystemRoles.Where( x => x.EmployeeRoleMenuMappings.Select(  m => m.MasterAppMenu.ParentMenuId==null  )  );
var roleMenuList = await roleMenuMappings.ToListAsync();
return View(roleMenuList);
```

I want to filter the records of SystemRoles Which have ParentMenuId null in MasterAppMenu table. SystemRoles have Icollection object EmployeeRoleMenuMappings which have this MasterAppMenu property.

Please tell me how to achieve this, i know it can be done on view side , but i want to do it on controller side only

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by `I want to filter the records of MasterAppMenu which has null value in field ParentMenuId`.

Comment: i have edited my question below code form

Comment: So each MasterAppMenu only has 1 ParentMenuId?

Comment: yes , i have told in my second of your answer it is not showing error if i remove any in that , but it doesnt filter also

Comment: I edited my answer to correct that!

Answer (score 0):

If you need all EmployeeRoleMenuMappings that have any null MasterAppMenu ParentMenuIds:

```
var roleMenuMappings = entities.EmployeeRoleMenuMappings
    .Where(m => m.MasterAppMenu.ParentMenuId == null);
```

You can also do it from SystemRoles level:

```
var systemRolesWithMenuMappings = entities.SystemRoles
    .Where(x => x.EmployeeRoleMenuMappings.Any(m => m.MasterAppMenu.ParentMenuId == null);
```

Or MasterAppMenus level:

```
var roleMenuMappings = entities.MasterAppMenu.Where(w => w.ParentMenuId == null);
```

Basically, you use Where() to filter the records. Within the Where() you use Any() because it returns a predicate or boolean value.

These queries will show only items that DO have a null value. If you want only items that DONT have a null value the just change it to `!= null` in the code.

Comment: thanks for the hep , but not working: FIrst it is giving error at m => m.MasterAppMenu.Any(a  => a.ParentMenuId==null) , not recognizing Any function

Comment: and even i do like this entities.SystemRoles.Where(x => x.EmployeeRoleMenuMappings.Any(m => m.MasterAppMenu.ParentMenuId == null)); it is running but not filtering records

Comment: Any() and Where() are both in System.Linq

Comment: yes but i guess Any can be applied collections objects

Comment: i have already tried that , it is not giving any errors , but not even filtering any records